# how to load a page in a parent div when the button is on childs div

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Hi im new in scripting i had this problem on how to load a page in parent div.
when i click the buttons in child div. i wanted to load a specific page in parent div.
by the way the codes in script are not mine.
[image]

when click view proj3

this is the result
[image]

index.php

```
         <div class="container-fluid">
                        <div id="a"></div>
                    </div>
    
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
      $('#project').click(function () {
              $('#a').load('project.php');
       });
    });    
    </script>
```

main.php

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div id="b"></div>
</div>
<script>
    function loadXMLDoc() {
      var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
          document.getElementById("b").innerHTML =
          this.responseText;
        }
      };
      xhttp.open("GET", "xxx.php", true);
      xhttp.send();
    }
    setInterval(function(){
        loadXMLDoc();
        // 1sec
    },1000);
    
    window.onload = loadXMLDoc;
</script>
```

xxx.php

```
    <a href="#"  id="view1">view proj1</a>
    <a href="#"  id="view2">view proj2</a>
    <a href="#"  id="view3">view proj3</a>
    
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
      $('#view1').click(function () {
              $('#a')load('project_view.php');
       });
      $('#view2').click(function () {
              $('#a')load('project_view.php');
       });
      $('#view3').click(function () {
              $('#a')load('project_view.php');
       });
    });    
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

### Try this: using `jquery`.

```html
<div style="background:#ccc; min-height: 300px; padding: 10px 10px;" id="parent_div">
    <div style="background: #000; display: block; padding: 10px 10px;" id="navigation_div">
  <a style="margin: 3px 5px; color: #fff;" href="project_view.php?id=project1">Project 1</a>
  <a style="margin: 3px 5px; color: #fff;" href="project_view.php?id=project2">Project 2</a>
  <a style="margin: 3px 5px; color: #fff;" href="project_view.php?id=project3">Project 3</a>
</div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(this).on('click', '#navigation_div a', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#parent_div', document).load($(this).attr('href')); // ex: href="project1.php"
  });
});
</script>
```

### Then your `project_view.php`

```
<?php

echo $_GET['id']; // will print the project1|project2|project3
```

Comment: this is working when all page are one, but my page has lots of content load from another file, but somehow I manage to work on it.